# Apache HttpComponents fails, HttpURLConnection works for same call

Tags: java, http, authorization, apache-httpcomponents

I need to use Apache `HttpComponents` for its `HttpMime` multipart libs. However, when making apparently exactly the same call with `HttpComponents` and stock `java.net` classes, `HttpComponents` fails:

```
private void getUrl(URI targeturl, String token) throws IOException {

    String AUTH = "Authorization";
    String OAUTH = "OAuth ";

    System.out.println("Impl1:");
    HttpGet htg = new HttpGet(targeturl);
    htg.addHeader(AUTH, OAUTH + token);
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(targeturl));
    System.out.println(response);
    String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(resp);

    System.out.println("\nImpl 2:");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uriToUrl(targeturl).openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty(AUTH, OAUTH + token);
    System.out.print(conn.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(" " + conn.getResponseMessage());

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(conn.getInputStream(), writer);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}

//for known good uris ONLY
private URL uriToUrl(URI uri) {
    try {
        return uri.toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        throw new Error(mue); //something is seriously fuxxored
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
Impl1:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Content-Length: 51, Content-Type: application/json, Date: Sat, 20 Jul 2013 00:03:42 GMT]
{"status":401,"data":null,"error":["Unauthorized"]}

Impl 2:
200 OK
{"status":200,"data":{...},"error":null}
```

HttpComponents is client 4.2.5, core 4.2.4, java is 1.6.0-24.
The setup appears identical to me, but there must be some difference. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dumb coding mistake.

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(targeturl));
```

should be

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(htg);
```